# How to add constraint to viewgroup instead of view?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-studio-3.0

I had a few group in my constraint layout, which I use it to show/hide its component. But then I notice I can add constraint to group(saw the Constraint Widget at Attributes). I tried resizing the group, adding constraint at Attributes, but nothing changed.

The only thing i found online regarding to group is that i can show/hide its component. Even according to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group , it doesnt seems like it's possible to add constraint to group.

My question is, is it possible to add constraint between groups instead of adding constraint to every single view?

Comment: i don't think its possible

Comment: The terminology is a little confusing. You can add constraints to [_ViewGroups_](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) but not to a [_Group_](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group) as a whole. A _ViewGroup_ is a special view that contains other views. A _Group_ is used to set visibility of the members in the group but, AFAIK, has no other functionality.

Comment: Was confusing ViewGroups with Group, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm providing an example you can check here how constrain to view-group work. Try this layout for any demo activity to check the functionality. Here you can see I have set `visibility="gone"` for view-group and set references for `Add` and `Done` buttons. So for child `add` and `done` buttons will be set as `visibility="gone"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="btnAdd,btnDone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="No buttons visible"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnAdd"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm, i think my question is confusing, i had changed to "is it possible to add constraint between groups instead of adding constraint to every single view?"